# Can I use SPD workflow to copy an item's field A to the same item's field B?

Tags: designer-workflow

On a list we have two column "Content" and "Approved Content". It is a rich html field. Whenever the list item's approval status = "Approved", the workflow will copy the "Content" value to "Approved Content". Is it possible?

We need to do it because SPD workflow do not have ability to get the last "approved" value of list item. It always get the latest value regardless it is approved, rejected or pending. We need to email out the "Approved content" so we come up an idea to store in another field on same list.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a condition like *approval status is equal to approved* and then put an action *set field to value* inside it (I don't have access to SPD at the moment). For *field* you take the target column (Approved Content) and for *value* you take the source column (Content) of the current item.

I used this for lookup columns, as they only store the IDs and not the string values.